# Fixing missing values in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have dataframe with below columns:

```
STORE   METHOD  DIVISION    PROB    VALUEX
20  1   5   0.85    0.759069373
20  2   5   0.85    2.663386705
20  3   5   0.85    2.511800796
20  1   6   0.85    0.170134162
20  3   6   0.85    0.921435575
20  3   7   0.85    0.947311849
20  1   8   0.85    3.394515939
20  2   8   0.85    0.844450117
20  3   8   0.85    0.813148774
```

So, for every DIVISION,PROB group column, we have three methods 1,2,3. If you observer for the division 5, it has all three methods (1,2,3) but for division 6, we have only 1,3 methods. So, in this case we need to add a new row for missing method (2 was missing in this case) with VALUEX column as mean of method 2 values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try pivot, fill value and unstack:

```
x = df.pivot_table(index=['STORE','DIVISION','PROB'],
               columns=['METHOD'], values='VALUEX')

means = x.mean(1)
x = x.apply(lambda s: s.fillna(means))

x.stack().reset_index(name='VALUEX')
```

Output:

```
    STORE  DIVISION  PROB  METHOD    VALUEX
0      20         5  0.85       1  0.759069
1      20         5  0.85       2  2.663387
2      20         5  0.85       3  2.511801
3      20         6  0.85       1  0.170134
4      20         6  0.85       2  0.545785
5      20         6  0.85       3  0.921436
6      20         7  0.85       1  0.947312
7      20         7  0.85       2  0.947312
8      20         7  0.85       3  0.947312
9      20         8  0.85       1  3.394516
10     20         8  0.85       2  0.844450
11     20         8  0.85       3  0.813149
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks, but how did you get the below value for                                                              20         6  0.85       2  0.545785                                                                                                     It has to be mean of method 2, so it should be ~1.75

Comment: As you said, it's the average of the same `STORE, DIVISION, PROB`. Print `x` right after the `pivot_table` to see. And then `means = x.mean(1)` takes averages along the rows, ignoring `NaN` which are the missing ones.

Comment: oh okay, i dont want average along the row but need average of the method (suppose if method 2 is missing, i want to insert average of method 2 values), how can i achieve that

Comment: forget `means = ...; x = x.apply` and replace with `x = x.fillna(x.mean())` which fill with means along the columns, i.e. by `METHOD`.